# How do I search a string for a keyword, then print whatever comes after that keyword

Tags: ios

I am currently using Tesseract to scan a document with the iPhone 6 camera, then process the text recognised and place it into a textView.

I've finally got that working and now I'd like to "check" what I've found, and then use that data to pre-populate other textfields or labels

For example;

```
myTextField.text = @"name: George, age: 17, gender: male, blah blah whatever else"
```

Now I want to search this text field and say something like:

```
If "substring "George:" is in string myTextField
nameLabel.text = text AFTER "George: " and BEFORE text ", age:"
```

I can create keywords within my file like "name: " and "age: " without duplicates, but I can't guarantee the length of the whole textfield since tesseract is not 100% accurate, hence the "blah blah" section, as some indistinguishable text may be present, which does not matter as long as I can extract those keywords

If there is no method like what I suggested, I assume something like

`find substring "name" and return stringPosition of` ,

then I can repeat for ", age" and then use the number values to attain the substring in-between points 6 and 13 to still give me George. Either is fine as I don't need the final result to be THAT efficient, as long as it works.

for example:

NSString *subs = @"the";
                NSString *wholeText = tesseractText.text;

```
            NSRange r = [wholeText rangeOfString:subs];
            if (r.location == NSNotFound)
            {
                tesseractText.text = @"No";
            }
            else
            {
                // The string to be searched for is in the text view, r.location contains where exactly it is.
                tesseractText.text = @"Yes";
            }
```

this works, even if there is errors in the reading/translation of the text, but if the method is "too" strict, then it may crash because random words fail to input properly

Comment: I think you mean find substring for "name:" not "George:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression 
    regularExpressionWithPattern: @"name: (.*?), age"]; 

[regexp.enumerateMatchesInString:myTextField.text 
    options:0 
    range:NSMakeRange(0, myTextField.text.length) 
    usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
    {
        NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        nameLabel.text = [myTextField.text substringWithRange:group1];
    }
];
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, I'll try it, thank you

Comment: I had to make some tweaks in the following parts but it worked, thank you very much:

NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"the (.*?) will" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil]; 
     [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:tesseractText.text options:0  range:NSMakeRange(0, tesseractText.text.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
 {
 NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
  myLabel.text = [tesseractText.text substringWithRange:group1];
                 }
                 ];

Answer (score 0):

if your string has this pattern

```
key: String, key: string, key: string,
```

than you can try to use `-componentsSeparatedByString:`

You will get an arrays of your long string, than you can but this in a dictionary

Comment: So you mean like:
key: name, key: age, key: gender...
then use componentsSeparatedByString: to find say, the first key: or the second key? Or to fill in an array using key to separate each part?

It sounds like it might help, but because my string uses Tesseract, some words don't fill properly and I can't control the exact length, so if the pattern is broken it wouldn't work would it? I think I need something a little more flexible to make up for reading errors, but I'll look into this and see if there's a way, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tapani I was able to construct a solution, incase anyone else has a similar need, here it is:

NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"the (.*?) will" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

// I use "the" and "will" because it's the file I had to hand with text I knew 100% would read, I can input the correct fields later

```
            [regexp enumerateMatchesInString:tesseractText.text
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, tesseractText.text.length)
                                  usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
             {
                 NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
                 myLabel.text = [tesseractText.text substringWithRange:group1];
             }
             ];
```